# Shared Microsoft Project on One Drive does not open

Tags: google-chrome, onedrive, microsoft-project

My colleague shared a Microsoft Project 2016 File on One Drive with me. It appears in my Shared folder, he has also given me rights to edit.

When I open One Drive on the web, I get the option to "Open in Project" when I click on that (tried with both Edge and Chrome) I get a warning and then I click OK, after which Microsoft Project Opens but with nothing on it.

Any idea how to use shared Project files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a workaround that worked for me.

When i click open in Project in a browser a alert box opens asking me if i want to open the file with the file URL. I press Ctrl+C on the alert box, paste it in notepad and copy the URL.

Then i open Microsoft Project 2016 and choose open file, and in the open file dialogue i paste the URL and it opens.

Answer (score 1):

I, too, have been having issues syncing the OneDrive folder with the Windows Explorer synced folder; all other MS Office applications sync just fine and have the editing or read-only capabilities clearly marked.  The only work-around I have been able to find is this: Open the MS Project (.mpp) file from Windows Explorer, make the edits, then "Save As" an updated version name.  Make sure your OneDrive (on the cloud)contains that file, then delete the original file from your Windows Explorer view; the OneDrive will update to show the new file has been loaded and the original file has been deleted.  You will have to rename the new file from the Windows Explorer view, as well; I have not been able to rename an MS Project file directly from my OneDrive view.

Comment: I figured out a way, check my answer below.